# How to fix disappearing Context Menus in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Not sure why this started happening, but it started today. I think I am using the word correctly, but any type of Context Menu that I pull up while in Chrome has been going invisible. Almost like a video glitch that semi-reappears when you move your mouse over it. It happens under favorite folders, extension options, or just right clicking on the webpage. Not knowing lingo well enough to search, I could not find anything in bug reports an what not.

Am I the only one getting this, it this due to the latest update, or is it possibly nothing to do with Chrome at all?

Thanks.

Comment: It happens with Chrome extension Context Menus too.

Answer (score 13):

I just fixed this on my Chrome browser.

1. Go into Chrome settings.
2. Click `Show Advanced Settings`.
3. Scroll down to the **System** section.
4. UNCHECK `Use hardware acceleration when available`.
5. Restart Chrome.

To access settings, go to `chrome://settings`

Comment: New info Jan 28:  Another fix:  Google Chrome Developers have identified this bug -- which primarily affects people with dual-monitors.  They have an initial "fix" for the bug in the new developer-oriented "Canary" browser for those who want to install that.  Presumably a normal Chrome fix will be released soon. Details here:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0jDqSbITTkA

Comment: Still a problem for me today with Chrome 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit), dual monitors. Turning of hardware acceleration did the trick, thanks.

Comment: Still a problem with Chrome 46.0.2490.71 m (64-bit) and dual monitors. Turning off hardware acceleration did it for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the latest dev version and this fixed it for me.

If you're happy doing this here the link:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/index.html?extra=devchannel#eula

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem wherein the area where search bar, history back/forward, bookmarks, etc. are found couldn't be seen anymore and instead I can see just blank area. When I click that blank area, it goes to desktop page.
I just fixed it after turning off my 2 monitors and now it's back to normal.
Not sure if that's the same as your problem.