# How to fix disappearing context menus in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Like another user described, I am experiencing a bug with Google Chrome's context menus disappearing. That question was here: [How to fix disappearing Context Menus in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/699347/how-to-fix-disappearing-context-menus-in-chrome)

After upgrading Chrome as suggested by Remirol, the error persists.

When the context menu disappears, the outline remains but only barely. 
On mouseover of the menu's selections the various selections will reappear individually.

See the attached screenshot images:

Initial outline, can you see it? 
[image]

Mouseover some but not all... 
[image]

Comment: I would try and disable `GPU Acceleration`.  If that works I would update my drivers to my graphics card and enable it again.  If that doesn't work try creating a new Chrome user profile.

Answer (score 11):

I just fixed this on my Chrome browser.

1. Go into Chrome settings.
2. Click "Show Advanced Settings".
3. Scroll down to the **System** section.
4. UNCHECK "Use hardware acceleration when available".
5. Restart Chrome.

Comment: New info Jan 28:  Another fix:  Google Chrome Developers have identified this bug -- which primarily affects people with dual-monitors.  They have an initial "fix" for the bug in the new developer-oriented "Canary" browser for those who want to install that.  Presumably a normal Chrome fix will be released soon. Details here:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0jDqSbITTkA

Comment: +1 This helped me too. And yes I do have a dual monitor configuration.

Comment: Same thing for me, with dual monitor. I was struggling several weeks until I found this answer :) Thx a lot!

Comment: This is NOT a fix - it is just a workaround.